# SQL Server does not recognize UNIQUE subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

When I wrote the statement below, I encountered a problem that `UNIQUE` key word is not recognized and program says that:

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNIQUE'."

How can I solve this problem?

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE UNIQUE
(SELECT CustomerID FROM SALES
 WHERE SALES.CustomerID = CUSTOMER.CustomerID);
```

Comment: That's correct: you can't use the unique keyword like that. Please read teh fine manual

Comment: That's actualy good question and it doesn't deserve downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such use of `WHERE` in SQL.

See documentation for *[Search Condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545.aspx)*.

You can count the rows from the sub-query and compare to 1:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE 1 = (SELECT count(CustomerID) 
           FROM SALES
           WHERE SALES.CustomerID = CUSTOMER.CustomerID);
```

Comment: `"There is no such use of WHERE in SQL."` - It is an overstatement. There is no such usage in T-SQL but `UNIQUE` is valid WHERE predicate in SQL standard.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `UNIQUE` in this context is perfectly valid and defined in SQL-92 standard.

[8.9 unique predicate](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-92-grammar.html#_8_9_unique_predicate)

> **Specify a test for the absence of duplicate rows.**
>
> ```
> <unique predicate> ::= UNIQUE <table subquery>
> ```

The point is that this predicate is now widely adopted by RDBMS vendors.

---

In your specific example the query could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE UNIQUE
(SELECT CustomerID FROM SALES
 WHERE SALES.CustomerID = CUSTOMER.CustomerID);

<=>

SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM (
      SELECT CustomerID
      FROM SALES
      WHERE SALES.CustomerID = CUSTOMER.CustomerID
  ) T
  WHERE (T.CustomerID) IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY T.CustomerID
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=21e44adea9911abc3913060582637c6e)**

Related: [UNIQUE predicate](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/unique-predicate/)